Validating only changed properties of a class file with FluentValidation
I have an endpoint that updates (PUTs) an entity.  However, the entire class file is not required, only the property the requestor wants to change.
How do I get FluentValidation to just validate the properties that are being updated?
For background, my class is a simple "Products" class and when it is initially created (POSTed), the following validations happen successfully:
    public class CreateProductCommandValidator:AbstractValidator<CreateProductCommand>
    {
        public CreateProductCommandValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Name is required");
            RuleFor(x => x.Category).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Category is required");
            RuleFor(x => x.ImageFile).NotEmpty().WithMessage("ImageFile is required");
            RuleFor(x => x.Price).GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Price must be greater than 0");
        }
    }

However, in my UpdateProductCommand class, if the requestor only updates the Name field, I just want to validate ONLY that field.  Otherwise, the requestor would have to put in all of the properties again and that just feels redundant.

I don't think that is how Fluent Validation works. In your scenario, you should do a mapping with the new property value with the existing entity. Then perform the validation.

You can write interfaces for each object you need to validate alone and build several validators for each interface and build a composite validator includes all simple validators so you can validate your product class.
